# How to send an automated email from Win XP Apache

Tags: php, apache, windows-xp, sendmail

I need to send myself an automated email once a day from my windows XP dev. machine. I've got Apache, PHP, and MySQL running here. I don't mind which email address the email gets sent from since i can add it to my address bar. I'm wondering though, what do i need to enable/install to be able to send emails?

Answer (score 1):

you can look into scheduled tasks that and commandline php. Commandline php lets you execute php files from the cmd for example php emailsend.php where you can use the mail() function. :)

Comment: Still need an MTA, and a normal LAMP stack on XP won't find a mail server.

Comment: ah didnt see he hadnt sendmail on it, can be downloaded and configured easily from apachefriends.org

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of mail transport agent - like sendmail.  You could theoretically use a PHP library for sending email and have it relay to an SMTP server hosted somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the swift mailer library

http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BLAT](http://www.blat.net/?faq/index.html):

You can set it up to run in a batch file and then use the Windows Task scheduler to execute the batch file at the specified time each day.